# How can I improve the performance of my geolocalization model in handling night images?

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a cosplace model in field of geolocalization and I need to improve its performance. One of the challenges of this model is not to localize night images well. Would you please help me a solution to gain my goal?

I added gussian and noise in the model but it led to about 3 percent decreasement in accuracy